# How to disable jNiceIt select tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have jNiceIT plugin for Jquery. How can i disable the select dropdown styled with jNiceIt?
It looks like this:

```
                <label for="titems">Select Box Control:</label>
                <div id="titems" tabindex="8" class="fmSelect" style="width: 40%; z-index: 1500;"><strong><span><cite>Value 1</cite></span></strong><ul style="display: none;"><li option="val_1" class="">Value 1</li><li option="val_2" class="">Value 2</li><li option="val_3" class="">Value 3</li><li option="val_4" class="">Value 4</li><li option="val_5">Value 5</li><li option="val_6">Value 6</li><li option="val_7">Value 7</li><li option="val_8">Value 8</li><li option="val_9">Value 9</li><li option="val_10">Value 10</li></ul></div>
                <select id="" name="items" tabindex="0" style="width: 100%; display: none;" class="fmZero">
                    <option value="val_1">Value 1</option>
                    <option value="val_2">Value 2</option>
                    <option value="val_3">Value 3</option>
                    <option value="val_4">Value 4</option>
                    <option value="val_5">Value 5</option>
                    <option value="val_6">Value 6</option>
                    <option value="val_7">Value 7</option>
                    <option value="val_8">Value 8</option>
                    <option value="val_9">Value 9</option>
                    <option value="val_10">Value 10</option>
                </select>
```

I've tried to set "disabled" on "true" for select but it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you show the code where you're setting "disabled" to "true"?

I'm not familiar with jNiceIt but have you tried using something like this?

```
// To disable 
$('.fmZero').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

Did you check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5891493/disabling-an-element-in-jquery-1-6) about disabling elements?

This answer looks promising: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891520/469643

Comment: I use $("select[name='players']").attr('disabled', 'disabled') but it does not work

Comment: If i try to use prop it tells i don't have this function.

Comment: I don't see a name='players' in your markup in your question. Have you tried name='items'? To do a sanity check perhaps you might want to give it an id and do "#id_you_set"

Comment: I created a jsfiddle for you to see; I removed most of your mark-up in order to isolate and display what is going on. You also had the select box set to display:none in your question; not sure if that was intentional or not. Here is [the example](http://jsfiddle.net/aJFUT/) for you to experiment with.